# How to split ui5 app

Tags: sapui5

I have been developing ui5 apps but working on my own on the whole app. Now I have to manage a team of developers that will be working on the same app. I have had a look at Git to manage the repository, but how can we split work to work all on the same app?

Answer (score 1):

It of course depends on the complexity of your app and the number of people you have in your development team.

Nevertheless, the first thing you have to consider is using a git branching model for the repository (e.g. feature branches, gitflow or http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). Having several active branches instead of only one (e.g. master) will reduce the number of merges.

Generally when working with git, it is best if you can split up work such that two developers don't need to touch the same file at the same time (to avoid conflicts which need manual merging). You can do this in UI5 by:

- Splitting components and [nesting them](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/2c66fb3eb775426087401117cfa6a94e.html).
- Splitting views and controllers and [nesting them](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/df8c9c3d79b54c928855162bafcd88ee.html).
- Splitting views into [fragments](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/234320f8d8ee45b39c60893116d60351.html).
- Composing the controllers out of [mixins](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/a-fresh-look-at-javascript-mixins/).

Normally, the granularity of the splitting will **not** affect your runtime performance drastically (given that you are building the UI5 app before deploy). This is because, during the build phase, all UI5 artifacts are merged into a single preload file.

If you will work on several apps together, you should also consider building a reuse library / component to share code between your apps (e.g. a controller base class, some formatters, adapters, etc).